# How to use custom locale in vis.js timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am using the vis.js timeline for a project and tried to add a custom locale as explained in the [documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Localization).

```
var options = {
  locales: {
    // create a new locale (text strings should be replaced with localized strings)
    mylocale: {
      current: 'current',
      time: 'time',
    }
  },

  // use the new locale
  locale: 'mylocale'
};
```

Although I'd like to make it work without moment.js I loaded moment.js before vis.js. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/e7uodse2/3154/) on jsfiddle that I expected to work but it doesn't. Can somebody please explain why it doesn't work as documented or if I missed something important?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some digging, you need to add these lines in this **order** :

load **moment js** first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

load **"fr"** since the example you provided in JSfiddle was in French

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your options:

```
const options {
  option: 'fr'
}
```

But you need to add:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

See https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/localization.html for example.